# Abusing faked user input in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, html5-fullscreen

I stumbled across the HTML5 fullscreen API which lets me set the browser to fullscreen mode from JavaScript. For further reading: http://demo.web3designs.com/javascript-jquery-fullscreen-browser-window-html5-technology.htm)

To prevent abuse it is only possible to "requestFullscreen" by a user gesture (e.g. user pressed a button). My question is if it would be possible to fake this "user gesture" with JavaScript, forcing the user in Fullscreen-Mode when he enters the page.

I already tried pressing a hidden button with JavaScript and that didn't work, but maybe there are other ways I am not aware of right now.

I know this would be a very bad practice and don't intend to use it on a public website.

Comment: If it isn't on a public website why not just use a browser with kiosk mode?

Comment: I have to use the Edge Browser and I couldn't find a way to start it in kiosk mode. If that would be possible it would be the perfect solution for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of enabling this *only by user gesture* is that it **cannot be automated**. If it could be automated by faking a user gesture, then this protection would fall extremely short of its intended purpose.

Browser vendors may in fact bend over backwards to really ensure something is triggered by user interaction and not by some automation. How far they bend and whether they leave any room to exploit and circumvent this will differ by vendor; but in general you should assume that "by user gesture" explicitly means "by user gesture and by user gesture alone".